# Converting child to parent object

Tags: c++, inheritance

I will describe my problem using a dummy example. Say we have a program of this architecture:

Parent class: Quadrilateral

Child classes: Rectangle, Rhombus, ...

First, a `vector<Rectangle>` and `vector<Rhombus>` are generated and make use of their child class properties. Later on, I would like to combine *all* quadrilaterals, i.e. combine both vectors into a single `vector<quadrilateral>`, since *I no longer need the child class properties*. Combining both vectors into one has the advantage that I can pass a reference to `vector<quadrilateral>` to other parts of my program where it is combined with data from other classes.

So my question is as follows: Is it possible to make a `Quadrilateral` out of a `Rectangle` by keeping only the parent variables from the `Rectangle`? Or is this a really bad idea and is there a much more elegant way to implement this?

EDIT:

after learning from the answers that this is referred to as **slicing**, I have read about it in [What is object slicing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing). I have decided to go with Mohamad's suggestion of using vectors of pointers instead, because I think it is an elegant solution that will likely give me the best performance.

Comment: maybe all what you need is to create a copy constructor for Parent class. correct me if  i'm wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can definitely do this by 'slicing' the derived portion of the object.

```
class Base {};
class Derived : public Base {};

Derived d;
Base b = d; // derived portion is sliced here
```

However in practise, I have never seen anyone who deliberately chose to slice their objects. We are usually warned against this as a 'gotacha' of C++.

Why not use a vector of pointers instead:

```
vector<Rectangle*>;
vector<Rhombus*>;
vector<quadrilateral*>;
```

That way no slicing occurs and you might gain from a performance boost if those classes are large since any copying the vectors might do would be on pointers and not entire objects.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this. You can create parent objects from child objects, as in following example:

```
struct Base { int base; };

struct Derived : Base { int derived; };

Derived der;
Base base = der;
```

The process is called `slicing`, and it works here because Base class will have default copy constructor, taking a const reference to Base. Since derived can be automatically converted to const reference to it's base, everything works like the charm. I am not sure about overall design, though. Usually slicing is to be avoided.

Following some questions in the comments, I believe, some clarification is in order.

Contrary to it appearance, `Base base = der;` does not call assignment operator. Instead, it calls copy constructor - this is the semantic of variable declaration. It is equivalent of `Base base(der)`. Here is more intruiging example:

```
struct A {
   A(int ) { };
   A() = default;
   // A(const A& ) = delete;
};

A a = 5; // Are your eyes fooling you?
```

Do not believe your eyes! There is never an operator= called - there is no even operator= in A defined. Instead, semantically A(int) constructor is called to create a temporary A, followed by copy constructor to create the a object. However, compilers usually optimize the call to copy-constructor away, and there is no redundant temporary copy created. In order to make sure this the case, uncomment copy-constructor marked `delete`, and the program will refuse to be compiled.

Comment: by looking at your code  you meant default ' copy assignment operator='  not 'copy constructor' correct me if I was wrong

Comment: @RichardGeorge, yes, you are very wrong. There is no assignment operator call in my code.

Comment: @RichardGeorge: This would use assignment operator: `Base base; base = der;`, `Base base = der;` does not. It's equivalent to `Base base( der );`

Comment: So there is no such thing like  Default copy assignment operator that do necessary task when you assign one compatable object to an another as told in websites and books

Comment: @RichardGeorge, of course there is! It is just not called here. I have updated my post to add some details on this.

Comment: A bit thing I am sure as you said for A a=5; the copy assignment won't call as 5 is an attribute not derived one is that the same for Base base=der;

Comment: @RichardGeorge, you are confused. Your confusion starts with the fact that you are mentioning non-existing 'copy assignments'. There are copy constructors and assignment operators, two different beasts. What do you mean by 'attribute not derived one' is completely beyond my comprehension.

Comment: Well ,I meant int 5 may be  an attribute or member of struct A but it is not a child of A,so the way = act will differ any way thank you for the replies I will watch out what confused me .